# Full calendar how to get no of events for particular time when an event renders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Hi friends i using jQuery Full calendar as a part for making an application. I went through code line in that

```
var sameDayList = view.eachElementOnDay(event);
```

this line returns me list of all events on particular day. my question is that is there any way to find out no of events on same time in full calendar.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [fullCalendar finding addtional events in the same day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721729/fullcalendar-finding-addtional-events-in-the-same-day)

I've seen similar questions, try searching this site for previous answers.